# Is there a gem that allows you to create migrations based on changes to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, database-migration

Is there a way to create a migration with changes you've made in a model?  For instance I have `Foo` model with `bar` and `oof` attributes already persisted in db.  I want to add the attribute `rab` to Foo.  Is there a way to add this attribute to the class and generate a migration that recognizes this change?

I would add `:rab` to `attr_accessible` in the Foo model file, and this magic function would create a migration like the following automatically:

```
class AutoMigrate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  add_column :foo, :rab, :string
end
```

Thanks.

Here's another thread I found with more info
[Rails - Generating migration script from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705181/rails-generating-migration-script-from-model)

It looks like DataMapper might be the solution I'm looking for, but I'm hesitent to move from ActiveRecord.

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-rails

Comment: I guess not, moreover, a new db field could be attr_protected but a mere instance variable could be attr_accessible. It's not a criteria

Comment: `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` are for mass assignment security. And they go away in Rails 4, so I'd not start using them now- instead, use Strong Parameters or Permitters (which use Strong Parameters) instead, as both work in Rails 3.1+. Strong Parameters is included in Rails 4, so strong_parameters should not be added to Gemfile if using Rails 4.

Comment: Not saying not to use DataMapper, but please read my answer and read through the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ You can create a migration for existing things you've done to the DB, but then you'd need to create records in the DB in the schema_migrations table indicating that they have already been run if using ActiveRecord, which is the standard ORM for Rails. There is an easier way to do what you want, which is `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and this is a bit backwards to how Rails expects to work.

One issue is that you'll often have `attr_accessible` properties that *aren't* supposed to be persisted, for example, a password field used to generate the persisted, encrypted password.

Comment: That's an adequate answer @Dave Newton, thank you.  Is there a way to do this by making an attribute essential in a model?

Comment: @JoeEssey Meh; you could create your own `attr_xxx`-style doodad that did the default `attr_accessible` stuff and also "marked" it as "essential", but you'd also need to persist whether or not it had already been added to a previous migration, too. IMO if you're adding persisted attrs do it the Rails way, which is via migration.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dave said, you're on the wrong track, somewhat.

ActiveRecord creates methods for each existing column in the database, e.g. if you have a foobar column in the table corresponding to the model, then you have a `foobar` method and a `foobar=(value)` method.

If you are starting fresh with a new Rails app, you can and should probably create the schema via migrations, and you can [use the migration generators built into Rails for that, and then tweak the migration files as needed](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) and run `rake db:migrate`.

If you are making changes to the database outside of Rails, then you can already access that via ActiveRecord, for the most part.

If you do `rake db:schema:dump`, you should be able to see the columns from the database already.

If you want to ensure that you have a backup of the schema (including SQL that is not part of an existing migration), consider using the `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` option in `config/application.rb`. Then instead of having `db/schema.rb`, you'll have a `db/structure.sql` with the schema creation SQL dumped into that file when you do `rake db:schema:dump`.

Per your comment in Dave's answer, you were also wanting to make an attribute required. You could do this via a migration that alters the column to make it not nullable. You can also add a validation to the model to require it. If you are learning and don't have to use them, don't use `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible`. Mass assignment security goes away in Rails 4, and you are getting confused by thinking they have to do with what is required (you'd use Strong Parameters instead anyway- see my comments to your question above). Required fields should usually be handled by DB restriction first (nullable or not and possibly constraints/triggers) then by validations- on the server side via ActiveRecord validations, then in the client-side in the HTML/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any gem like that or even how it would be possible to implement.
Its reverse of the convention. Also the main problem would be how to know the attribute type from adding something to `attr_accessible`. there is no way to know if its a string or float, etc. Just follow the convention and dont edit the `schema.rb file`.

Just generate a new migration to add the attribute to the Foo model

```
rails generate migration add_rab_to_foo rab:string
```

then run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```